# How to understand call destructor method in CPP?

Tags: c++, destructor

I am trying to understand the Destructor method in CPP. 
I have known facts:
a. Destructor method would be automatically called when the instance ends.
b. If no explicit destructor methods defined, then compiler would create a default Destructor (though no specific task would be done such as no clean up user's dynamic memory.)

So Suppose A is a class name, I would like to know how many times class A's destructor would be called:

What I understand now is that the very last line of "delete []p" cannot be considered as a Destructor, it is just used to delete dynamic pointer p.
Since there is no information in A's class whether an explicitly destructor created,  we think that a default class destructor created, thus twice called for p (because there are two elements in A[2]), and once for p2, total three times.

I am not sure whether above is correct or not. Hope CPP guru here could help me out. Thanks!!

```
int main(){
    A *p = new A[2];
    A * p2 = new A;
    A a;
    delete []p;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? Write a class with a destructor and print something to stdout. http://cpp.sh/7cqsw

Comment: "and once for p2" - um. no. There is no `delete p2;` there is no `A::~A()` invoked for `p2`. The three times are for destruction of `a`, and destruction of the sequence `p`, the former by scope, the latter by *you*.

Comment: @tkausl Cool thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A destructor is going to get called exactly once for every instance of a class. I am excluding the marginal case of program termination making the entire process go away without invoking the oustanding objects' destructors (no point to it).

In your example, `p` is a pointer to an array containing two instances of a class. `delete[] p` is going to destroy two instances of the class. The class's destructor gets called once for each object getting destroyed, for a total of two times. `p2` is a pointer to one instance of the class, but since it is not explicitly `delete`d, that one falls into the marginal case. Finally, there's an instance of the class in function automatic scope. That instance gets destroyed when execution leaves the function scope, so that's another destructor call.

Whether or not a class has a default destructor, or an explicitly declared destructor, that makes no difference. Whatever destructor that class has, that destructor gets called.

Now, keep in mind that even though the destructor gets invoked multiple times here, it is being invoked exactly once for each instance of the class getting destroyed, and you have multiple instances.

Comment: Thank you @samvarshavchik ! really helps me a lot!